# Conexión con Base de Datos local PHP - SQL Server (local)

Tags: php, sql-server

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un sql server express local que tengo en mi equipo.
Luego tengo el xamp instalado y en la carpeta htdocs tengo el código php para intentar extraer datos de la BBDD.
Me da el siguiente Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\selectall.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\selectall.php(3):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=D...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\selectall.php on line 3

Probablemente está en alto tan simple como que esté usando mal el usuario y contraseña.
Al estar en local no se si debo usar la ip que tengo (172.26.0.93) y no se que contraseña.
Usar loscalhost y de contraseña vacío o root
O usar el nombre del equipo y la conexión como la hago en el managment:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código php:

```
    <?php
//---------------------------------Consulta Agenda---------------------------------   
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=DESKTOP-6C68BFU\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Inventario", "root", "");
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT [NOMBRE]
,[MODELO]
FROM [Inventario].[dbo].[MARCA]");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te da un error de driver, no de usuario/contraseña o host.

Si tienes la última versión de XAMPP lo más probable es que en realidad sí tengas instalado el driver ya que viene incluido en las últimas versiones de PHP (7.0, 7.1 y 7.2) como indican en su el último release del repositorio:

> We are pleased to announce the production release of the Microsoft
>   Drivers for PHP for SQL Server. The SQLSRV and PDO_SQLSRV drivers have
>   been built with PHP 7.0, 7.1, and 7.2 and tested on all supported
>   platforms.

Fíjate que lo tengas descomentado en tu php.ini.
Búsca *sqlsrv* y fíjate que la línea no tenga un punto y coma delante.

Te dejo un enlace con la explicación sobre el tema del driver [Driver PHP SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Muchas gracias era eso!

Comment: @YasielHernández si puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta entonces, gracias